# python reverse/transponse a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking to tranpose a dictionary on python and after looking around i was not able to ifnd a solution for this. Does anybody know how could i reverse a dictionary like the following as input:

> ```
> graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
>              'B': ['C', 'D'],
>              'C': ['D'],
>              'D': ['C'],
>              'E': ['F'],
>              'F': ['C']}
> ```

so that i get something like:

```
newgraph = {'A': [''],
         'B': ['A'],
         'C': ['A', 'B', 'D','F'],
         'D': ['B', 'C'],
         'E': [''],
         'F': ['E']}
```

Comment: Why is F missing from the result for C?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo! will update

Comment: Why is F missing from the result for C and E has result 'F'?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
newgraph = defaultdict(list)
for x, adj in graph.items():
    for y in adj:
        newgraph[y].append(x)
```

While it doesn't seem to make any sense to have the empty string `''` in the empty lists, it's certainly possible:

```
for x in newgraph:
    newgraph[x] = newgraph[x] or ['']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
...              'B': ['C', 'D'],
...              'C': ['D'],
...              'D': ['C'],
...              'E': ['F'],
...              'F': ['C']}
>>> new_graph = defaultdict(list)
>>> for ele in graph.keys():
...     new_graph[ele] = []
...
>>> for k, v in graph.items():
...     for ele in v:
...             new_graph[ele].append(k)
...
>>> pprint(new_graph)
{'A': [],
 'B': ['A'],
 'C': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'],
 'D': ['B', 'C'],
 'E': [],
 'F': ['E']}
```

Comment: OP specifies that `'A'` should map to a list containing an empty string (`'A': ['']`).  Your answer makes more sense because if you request `new_graph['A']` you get an empty list, which is a better representation of no values.  I wonder whether it makes sense to insert the empty lists because the defaultdict will create them on demand.

Comment: I fixed that a moment ago. :)

Comment: how did you manage to get that order while printing. for some reason i get>>>['A', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'M']

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible without `defaultdict`.
Here I've left the empty keys in the new dict with the value None.

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
             'B': ['C', 'D'],
             'C': ['D'],
             'D': ['C'],
             'E': ['F'],
             'F': ['C']}

g = dict.fromkeys(graph.keys())
for k, v in graph.iteritems():
  for x in v:
    if g[x]: g[x] += [k]
    else:    g[x] = [k]

for k in sorted(graph.keys()):
  print k, ':', g[k]
```

Output:

```
A : None
B : ['A']
C : ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']
D : ['C', 'B']
E : None
F : ['E']
```